# Returning a local variable from a function and using it in the calling function

Tags: c

Is the following program correct? I return the local variable `x` from function `fun` and use it in the calling function. Can anyone explain if there is anything wrong with returning a local variable even if it contains the valid address in `main`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int j) {
    int x = j;

    return x;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", fun(1));

    // OR
    int k = 9;
    printf("%d\n", fun(k));

    // OR
    printf("%d\n", fun(&k));
    
    return 0;
}
```

If my code is wrong then why is it?

Comment: You return the *value* of `x`, not `x` itself. The value is *copied* and used by the calling function.

Comment: With that said, the call `fun(&k)` is wrong and the compiler should complain about it. The `fun` function expects an `int` argument, not `int *` (which is the type of `&k`). This problem doesn't change the fact that `fun` returns an `int` value by copy.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what if the signature of the function was `int fun(int *j)`?

Comment: Doesn't matter, you would still return an `int` value by copying it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if the signature is `int fun(int j)` then is the error. got it. can I debug it with valgrind or `massif` can u please tell me specific commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is OK in C for a function to return the value of a local object. The compiler generates code to copy this value to the object into which the function return value is stored or used in an expression. The local object can be a scalar or a structure alike.

Conversely, returning a pointer to a local object is not OK because the object pointed to will have gone out of scope by the time the pointer is dereferenced by the caller.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int good(int j) {
    int x = j;
    return x;     // OK
}

int *bad(int j) {
    int x = j;
    return &x;    // NOT OK
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", good(1));  // prints 1

    int k = 9;
    printf("%d\n", good(k));  // prints 9

    printf("%d\n", *bad(1));  // undefined behavior
    
    return 0;
}
```

The posted code in incorrect here: `printf("%d\n", fun(&k));` because `fun` expects an `int` argument, not a pointer to `int`.

Comment: is this behavior also correct for `struct` for example if I have `struct obj func(struct obj o){ struct obj b=o; return o;}` OR `struct obj func(struct obj *o){ struct obj b=o; return o;}`?

Comment: @user786: `struct obj func(struct obj o){ struct obj b = o; return o;}` is correct, as well as `struct obj func(struct obj o){ struct obj b = o; return b;}`. The second example should be modified as `struct obj func(struct obj *o){ struct obj b = *o; return b;}`.